# Postgres JSONB Check if JSON contains string using JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in my posgtgres table the json is of structure : {'alias':["name1","name2","name"....]}

I have written the Postgres query to check if the array in the JSON object contains the name.

```
select * from public.table t where json_col->'alias' ? 'name'
```

this works on pgAdmin

But same doesn't work in JPA

My code

```
@Query(value = "select * from public.table t where json_col->'alias' ? :name" ,nativeQuery = true)
    Table findUsingName(@Param("name") String name);
```

This throws an error : 'Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!'

I understand this error is due to the fact ? is also used by JPA is different sense...

Can anyone help me in the JPA Query

Comment: Try `??` instead. I think the JDBC driver will detect that's an "escaped" `?` operator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `?` operator does, but you should use the named variant of the operator as a `?` in JDBC is used to define a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Found the postgres function for '?' i.e. jsonb_exists_any(company_alias->'alias',ARRAY[:name])

Comment: The disadvantage of using the function is that it can't make use of an index if you need that for performance reasons.

Comment: I tried ?? but this the error: 'Mixing of? parameters and other forms like ? 1 is not supported!'
I had no other option